# Write Permission issue on PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, centos

I am having problem that apache can't write file via PHP (for example, write csv file) - I have to change file permission to 777 and it work but it is very bad security. I am trying to use sufficient permissions to write, maybe 664. What went wrong?

Apache is running as `apache` and group is also `apache`. All the files in `/var/www/html` are owned by root and group is `web-content`

I can login to FTP client and read/write files to `/var/www/html` without any problem.

I have created an ftp user called intranet, here what I did:

```
groupadd web-content
usermod -G web-content intranet
chown root:web-content /var/www/html
chmod o+rx /var/www/html
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
```

ls -la /var/www/

```
drwxrwxr-x.  4 root web-content 4.0K Sep  6 16:09 html
```

When I upload new files on FTP.

ls -la /var/www/intranet/

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 intranet intranet       0 Sep  6 17:42 test
```

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? is it running as the same user as apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
7 - owner bits, read/write/execute
5 - group bits, read/execute
5 - everyone else bits, read/execute
```

Since the file is 755, only the owner has write permissions. You've got apache running as `apache`, and the file is owned by `root`, so the owners don't match, and you end up with no write permissions.

You'd probably want to chown the file to `apache:web-content` or at least `root:web-content` and make the file 575 instead, so that the group permissions match up.

Comment: Thanks, that seem to fixed when I apply `root:web-content` again. I've notice when I upload file on FTP client the owner and group changed to `-rw-r--r--.  1 intranet intranet       0 Sep  6 17:42 test` which can cause a bit of problem for write permission. I am using `vsftd` server.